# Non-Regular Differential Equation soultion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently a freshman at Japanese University and studying ordinary differential equation. I faced one problem which I could not solve.

$$y=-xp+x^4p^2$$ $$p=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Can someone teach me how to solve this equation?

Comment: Try solving for $p = f(x, y)$ (treat it like a quadratic) and then for each $p$, make the substitution $$y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x$$ and solve and then substitute back.

Comment: the solution Looks terrible

Comment: @Moo I am still not quite sure how to solve the equation using that substitution. I have used this type of substitution for a homogeneous equation, but not for the other kind of equation. If you have time, can you explain the step I should take to solve the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=u^{-1}$, $v(u)=y(x)=y(u^{-1})$, then $y'(x)=-x^{-2}v'(u)=-u^2v'(u)$ and in consequence
$$
v(u)=uv'(u)+v'(u)^2
$$
which now is a classical **Clairaut differential equation** with derivative $0=v''(u+2v')$. It has linear solutions
$$
v(u)=cu+c^2\iff y(x)=\frac{c}x+c^2
$$
and a singular solution given by $u+2v'(u)=0$, that is
$$
v(u)=-\frac{u^2}4\iff y(x)=-\frac1{4x^2}.
$$
As the first family is tangent to the singular solution, one can also assemble piecewise solutions that move for some time along the singular solution and continue before and/or after along a solution of the family.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the reference to Clairaut equation. I did not remember about it or the more general Lagrange equation, which also has a simple way of solving it

Comment: I think I got it! This way of solving equation looks pretty effective in general for ODE. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a trick, but the way to solve this is to interchange the dependent and independent variable. So, consider the differential equation as an equation for $x(y)$, using $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} = \left(\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} y}\right)^{-1}$. Then, using the substitution
$$
 \xi(y) = 4 y^2 x(y) -1,
$$
you'll have no problem solving the differential equation.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out your point, but I think I got it. Very interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve problems like this one.

From the second equation, changing the variable to $p$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dp}\frac{dp}{dx}=p$$

From the first equation we find the first derivative:

$$\frac{dy}{dp}=-p\frac{dx}{dp} -x+2p x^4+4p^2 x^3 \frac{dx}{dp}$$

Substituting:

$$\frac{dy}{dp}\frac{dp}{dx}=-p-x\frac{dp}{dx}+2x^4 p \frac{dp}{dx}+4x^3 p^2=(4x^3p-1)p+x(2x^3p-1)\frac{dp}{dx}$$

From the second equation again:

$$(4x^3p-1)p+x(2x^3p-1)\frac{dp}{dx}=p$$

$$2(2x^3p-1)p+x(2x^3p-1)\frac{dp}{dx}=0$$

> $$(2x^3p-1) \left(2p+x \frac{dp}{dx} \right)=0$$

This separates into two equations, one algebraic and one separable ODE.

Comment: The more systematic way is to use $\dot y = p\dot x$ where the derivatives are for $p$. Then $$p\dot x = -x-p\dot x+4x^3\dot xp^2+2x^4p\\\iff\\x-2x^4p=-2\dot x(p-2x^3p^2)\\\iff\\(x-2p\dot x)(1-2x^3p)=0$$ which is materially different from your equation and provides the solutions $x(p)^2=Cp$ and $p=-\frac12x^{-2}$.

Comment: @LutzL, do you also mean that the equation I obtained is not correct (not consistent with the initial system)? I'll try to check numerically later

Comment: Yes. In the second equation you have the derivative of $x^4$ as $3x^3$ which is not a typo as it is also repeated in the subsequent equations.

Comment: @LutzL, thank you, I fixed the mistake, though the sign inside one of the brackets is different from what you obtained. I'll check for more errors. Thank you again

Comment: To me, this way to solve the equation was very new and fascinating. Thank you so much!