# Is there a way to obtain the solution to this nonlinear ODE in explicit form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I considered a generalization of the ODE from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631194/269624). The generalization depends on $4$ parameters and has the form:

$$y=axp+bx^rp^s \tag{1} $$ $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=p  \tag{2}$$

Where $a,b,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ with some appropriate conditions if needed.

The equation is not separable in the general case.

The most convenient way would be to reduce it to [Clairaut's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation) (as was done for the particular case in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2631395/269624)), but I don't see how it could be done for general $r,s$, at least not with the same kind of substitution.

It also doesn't fit the description of Lagrange differential equation, because of the $x^r$ term.

---

The only method of solution I figured out so far is the one I attempted in the linked question, based on reducing the problem to exact differential equation.

Differentiate (1) w.r.t. $p$:

$$\frac{dy}{dp}=(ap+brx^{r-1}p^s) \frac{dx}{dp}+(ax+bsx^rp^{s-1})$$

Multiply by $\frac{dp}{dx}$ and substitute in (2):

$$p=(ap+brx^{r-1}p^s)+(ax+bsx^rp^{s-1})\frac{dp}{dx}$$

Now the equation has the form:

> $$((a-1)p+brx^{r-1}p^s)dx+(ax+bsx^rp^{s-1})dp=0$$

Introducing the integrating factor in the form $\mu=x^\alpha p^\beta$ we can find:

$$\alpha=-\frac{r}{a(r-s)+s} \qquad \beta=-\frac{s}{a(r-s)+s}$$

And after integrating the implicit solution looks like this:

> $$\frac{a}{\beta+1} x^{\alpha+1} p^{\beta+1}+\frac{bs}{\beta+s} x^{\alpha+r} p^{\beta+s}=C_1 \tag{3}$$

Together (1) and (3) give the solution in parametric form.

The equation (3) can be solved by Newton-Raphson for example.

---

However, there's likely a better method of solving this equation, which is why I am asking:

> (a) Does (1), (2) reduce to some well known equation for general values of parameters?
>
> (b) Is there a better way of solving it, again, for the general case? Preferably in explicit form, unlike the way I did it.